# Spring 4 mvc I always get Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

My issue is that I get always `Request method 'POST' not supported` !
I'm trying to test my rest web webservice. Here is the WS :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addGouvernorate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<Gouvernorate> addGouvernorateee(@RequestBody Gouvernorate gouvernorate) throws IOException {
        gouvernorateService.addGouvernorat(gouvernorate);
        return new ResponseEntity<Gouvernorate>(gouvernorate, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

i'm trying to call it with jsoup as follows :

```
package test.sofiane.rqs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String base64login = new String(Base64.encode("sof:1".getBytes()));
        Response docs = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/site/data/addGouvernorate")
                .data("name", "name")
                .data("delegation", "delegation")
                .data("district", "district")
                .data("postalCode", "postalCode")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
    }
}
```

I get the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=http://localhost:8080/mintad/data/addGouvernorate
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:459)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
    at test.sofiane.rqs.Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

And with Postman application I get

```
Etat HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I'm using spring security also.

as follow

```
package com.site.spring.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

/**
 * @author Sofiane
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            //.antMatchers("/admin/**").denyAll()//.access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/404");
        // @formatter:off
    }
}
```

A guess : it can be the csrftoken which I have to send since I'm behind spring security but how to generate it ?
Please help because it's driving me insane guys

Comment: You don't need to generate the csrf token by yourself, spring security do this for you. You need to be proof that you have this token on your site.You need two params, `_csrf` and `_csrf_header` but I'm not familiar with your solution in `Test`. For more details: https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security try the `csrf()` method

Comment: @ManuZi thanks a lot for this url. I'll check it tonight.